# Selenium WebDriver and Robot: making it focus on the right browser when automating a file upload

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, awtrobot

I'm trying to induce an error on my website where you try to add to many images to an object from a native upload window (sendKeys will not work in this situation; it does not induce the error). 1 out of 5 times, it will do what's intended-- add too many pictures. Other times, it will make the clicks, but do them in the wrong browser, or even in just Eclipse

Here's what I have. This snippet logs you in and gets you to the add item

```
  public void addItemMoreThan10Images() throws AWTException{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://example.com/login");
    loginClass login = new loginClass(driver);
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    login.VerifyLoginUser();
    login.typeUserName("example");
    login.typePassword("example");
    login.clickOnLoginButton();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(login.profileInfo));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'New Item')]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'New Item')]")).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/item-wizard/div/div/form/div[3]/input")));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[@class='PhotoTxt margClear']")).click();
```

And then, this is where the interesting stuff happens.

```
try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

@Test(priority=1) 
public void testAddItemMoreThan10Images()
{
    try {
        addItemMoreThan10Images();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So, as a result, this code does clicks, but does not do them, much of the time, in the right place. Does anyone have any advice as for how to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code is pretty "punk" :-) On the first look, some keyRelease events are missing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll give more keyreleases a go